# How i can get the unit vector from the angular velocity vector?

Tags: vector

I have a planer link which is rotating about the z axis and tip of that link moves in a straight line path. it means that values of theta is continiously increasing and decreasing with respect to a point. I have the information of angular velocity vector for every instant of time.

**How i can get the unit vector from the angular velocity vector ?**

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: w2_0_0cap = w2_0_0/(normw2_0_0);                                                                          Here w2_0_0cap  is unit vector and w2_0_0 is angular velocity vector. this is not working for the negative values